# password protected folders

Tags: password, encryption

Is it possible to create password protected folders on the desktop?

Other people use my computer from time to time and it would be useful to have this facility.

Answer (score 0):

You could let your guests use a different user and properly set permissions for you files/folders to prevent access from the other user account.

Another way to go would be to encrypt the files/folder that you don't want other people to access and then require a password to decrypt those files.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is Simply Zip the files with Password Protection.
7-Zip Program has very good Password Protection/Encryption.